# Android resource failed help meee

Tags: android

Android resource linking failed
ERROR:C:\Users\no\AndroidStudioProjects\Tugas1\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml:92: AAPT: error: '@+array/pilihkelas' is incompatible with attribute entries (attr) reference.

ERROR:C:\Users\no\AndroidStudioProjects\Tugas1\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml:104: AAPT: error: '@+array/pilihagama' is incompatible with attribute entries (attr) reference.

Comment: You have assigned `@array` to  wrong property somewhere in the `activity_main.xml` ..

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the error, it's very clear. It says

> ERROR:C:\Users\no\AndroidStudioProjects\Tugas1\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml:92: AAPT: error: '@+array/pilihkelas' is incompatible with attribute entries (attr) reference.

Where you can see the problem is in the `activity_main.xml` line 92, where you add an `array` as `@+array/pilihkelas` where the entry you put there is not compatible with an `array`.

An example would be :

```
 <ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:entries="@array/numbers" <--
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

Perhaps the problem is the "+" symbol.